# sql query for convert(varbinary, [login])

Tags: sql-server

I have my sql query to check for permission of the user

```
select column 1 ,column 2 ,column 3  ,column 4 from usertable where convert(varbinary, [login]) = convert(varbinary, 'demo_RBC')
```

This query doesnt return any reocrd though the table has a entry for demo_RBC .The same query works for any other string like demo_BDCA or demo_avm.

Is there any specific reason why demo_RBC string doesnt work in the comparision of the where clause.Is there a better wat to check the login criteria.

Comment: Not working how? Error? Or just not matching?  Pretty sure varbinary is case sensitive are you sure its a 100% match?  If the `login` isn't stored in varbinary why do you need to convert to compare?

Comment: can be worth checking if the [login] field has any chars like trailing spaces, newlines etc

Comment: Are you trying to make a case sensetive comparison? You would rather specify a collation that does that instead of converting the strings to a binary format.

Comment: yes , i am try to do a case sensitive comparision .Could you let me know how can i modify the query to use collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with collation, ie `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

Here is a sample to demonstrate:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var = 'Hello'

SELECT 1
WHERE 'HELLO' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = @var

set @var = 'HELLO'

SELECT 1
WHERE 'HELLO' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = @var
```